# .NET Core api controller get object with HttpGet attiribute from client Side Axios

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, vue.js, asp.net-core

My .NET Core program is Api Controller program.
Using HttpGet, I want to get the object from the client on the controller. But I am getting Unsupported media type error. The codes are client side and server side:,

Client side:

```
  const getGmcList = async(lazyParams:any)=>{
    let res = await api.get(END_POINT+"GetGmcList",lazyParams);
    let data = res.data?.Value;
    return data;
  };
```

Server side :

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GmcController : ControllerBase
    {
        GmcManager gmcManager;
        public GmcController(GmcManager gmcManager)
        {
            this.gmcManager=gmcManager;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<BLLResultList<GMC_DATA>> GetGmcList(GmcParams gmcParams)
        {
            return await gmcManager.GetGmcList();
        }
```

Comment: the type of data your sending is incompatible with the expected type being received.  No one here can tell you exactly how to fix it because only you know what kind of data `lazyParams` contains, or what `GmcParams` type means. The answer may also depend on what version of .NET Core which you did not specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) in your client side. Sample code like below:

```
const getGmcList = async(lazyParams:any)=>{
    // add this line
    let params = new URLSearchParams(lazyParams).toString();
    let res = await api.get(END_POINT+"GetGmcList?" + params);
    let data = res.data?.Value;
    return data;
};
```